# Limiting extension method to target EF Entities only

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I've made an extension method which I use to make serializable dictionaries from EF Entities:

```
public static class Extensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToSerializable(this object obj)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList())
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(obj, null);

            if (value != null && (value.GetType().IsPrimitive 
                  || value is decimal || value is string || value is DateTime 
                  || value is List<object>))
            {
                result.Add(property.Name, value);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

I'm using it like this:

```
using(MyDbContext context = new MyDbContext())
{
    var someEntity = context.SomeEntity.FirstOrDefault();
    var serializableEntity = someEntity.ToSerializable();
}
```

I would like to know if there is any way to constrain it to be usable on my entities only, instead of all `object`:s.

Comment: Can you use a common base class, even empty, and inherits from it?

Comment: It would require a little bit of manual work, but you could declare a marker interface (e.g. `IEntity`), make every entity implement that interface and then attach the extension method to `IEntity`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code for Patryk's answer:

```
public interface ISerializableEntity { };

public class CustomerEntity : ISerializableEntity
{
    ....
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static IDictionary<string, object> ToSerializable(
        this ISerializableEntity obj)
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        foreach (var property in obj.GetType().GetProperties().ToList())
        {
            var value = property.GetValue(obj, null);

            if (value != null && (value.GetType().IsPrimitive 
                  || value is decimal || value is string || value is DateTime 
                  || value is List<object>))
            {
                result.Add(property.Name, value);
            }
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

Seeing how this code works with the marker interface, you may choose to put the serialization method in the interface to avoid the reflection and to have finer control on what gets serialized and how it might be encoded or encrypted:

```
public interface ISerializableEntity 
{
    Dictionary<string, object> ToDictionary();
};

public class CustomerEntity : ISerializableEntity
{
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string CustomerPrivateData { get; set; }
    public object DoNotSerializeCustomerData { get; set; }

    Dictionary<string, object> ISerializableEntity.ToDictionary()
    {
        var result = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        result.Add("CustomerName", CustomerName);

        var encryptedPrivateData = // Encrypt the string data here
        result.Add("EncryptedCustomerPrivateData", encryptedPrivateData);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static IDictionary<string, T> ToSerializable(this T obj) where T:Class
```

Will narrow it down a bit. If you need more than that you will need to assign a marker interface to all entities and use:

```
public static IDictionary<string, T> ToSerializable(this T obj) where T:IEntity
```